# Check db status through DATABASE_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pg, heroku-postgres

I've been given access to Heroku application with rather strange setup. It has one database but when I run `heroku config`, I get different DATABASE_URL and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL.
When I run `heroku pg:info` I get the following result:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-09-05 11:02 UTC
Data Size:   6.5 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

I realised that my database is at DATABASE_URL, but I can't access that database, only through `heroku run console`. All `heroku pg` commands fail with this message:

```
!    Unknown database: DATABASE_URL. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
```

If I run `heroku pg HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL`, I get access to empty database from above.

Since I have some issues with running migrations, I think my database might be full, and I'd like to check it. Any ideas how I can do that?

Here's the error after I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  permission denied for relation schema_migrations
: INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20130918114202')
```

More information about the setup:

rails 3.2.12

RAILS_ENV: staging (I don't have access to production, but I know this is "dev" server and there's also real "staging" from which this app was forked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like something screwy on the Heroku side.  Have you tried submitting a ticket with them?  I've always had good luck with their support.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I'll do that and update this thread when I get their reply.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem and i fixed it:

Just Keep a Backup from your database and restore it back again, here is the steps:

```
heroku pg:info                 <-- to get the Database Name
heroku addons:add pgbackups    <-- make sure you have the addons for backup
heroku pgbackups:capture       <-- Capture the backup
heroku pgbackups               <-- check your backups and make sure its there 
heroku pg:reset  DATABASE_NAME <-- Reset your database don't worry we have a backup, replace DATABASE_NAME with database name
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_NAME b001 <-- Restore the backup again, replace DATABASE_NAME with database name and b001 with your Database version you can see this version number in heroku pgbackups step
heroku run rake db:migrate     <-- Now you can run your migration and Operate in normal mode.
```

Comment: Hey, you totally rock, dude !! This was a perfect solution for me (I had the same `permission denied` error on db:migrate. Thanks ! (And now, I know how to make a DB backup/restore).

Answer (score 0):

I just got an update from my client. Before, I couldn't drop the database, because of the data in it. At the end, we decided to drop the database since the data can be added back (it's dev server, doesn't matter if we loose some dummy data).

I didn't find a solution for the problem above, but promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL and restoring from backup solved the issue about not being able to access the database.